# Opening powerpoint with Libre Office from mac terminal

Tags: mac, terminal, libreoffice

I use the terminal a lot in Ubuntu, but I also have two macs.

I'd like to open a powerpoint with Libre Office Impress from terminal on my mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: To assume LibreOffice is installed on the mac(s) use the same commands with the obviously  modified paths that mac vs.  ubuntu  presents you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `soffice`.  `soffice -help` should give you some idea of how it's used, eg:

```
soffice [options] <filename>
```

For powerpoint, the option will be `--impress`.  If for some reason you don't find soffice, then try:

```
locate soffice
```

That should point to something in your `/Applications` folder.  You can add that to your path or make a soft link into your `~/bin` (and add that to your path).

Comment: Perfect! Just tested in Ubuntu and working great too!

Comment: Good thing.  You can accept that as an answer by clicking the check mark.  Thanks.